# How to Fade Out an Element when Another Element Fade in

Tags: jquery, html, css

Right now the code that I am using to try and get this to work does not seem to function correctly. h7 represents the element that is fading in while the class of back is the element that is going to fade out when h7 fades in. I hope to get this to work both ways

```
if ($("h7").css("display", "block")) {
    $(".back").hide("fast");
}           
else if ($("h7").css("display", "none")) {
    $(".back").show(500);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `css` as setter which returns a jQuery object and an object is always `true` in JavaScript, you can use `:visible` selector and `is` method.

```
if ($("h7").is(":visible")) {
    $(".back").hide("fast");
}
else {
    $(".back").show(500);
}
```

Note that `h7` is not valid element.

Comment: Great answer, but just short note to OP for the future: _Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout_. (source: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: The code you provided does not seem to work correctly. Nothing happens to the back class when h7 is visible. Thanks though.

Comment: @undefined - Offtopic: Does browser really know visibility status of non-valid `h7` element?

Comment: Strange, I've never thought that is possible :)